# PlayFramework 2.2 doesnt work on Mac os X mavericks

Tags: macos, playframework, osx-mavericks

I did everything but i cant run play :/ so this is my error snapshot.Java 1.8 isntalled..
i tried brew also same end. if its possible to know whats is problem please help. thanks in advance.

```
sudo play
Password:
java.lang.Error: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:105)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:94)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<clinit>(UNIXProcess.java:92)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.exec(TerminalLineSettings.java:183)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.exec(TerminalLineSettings.java:173)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.stty(TerminalLineSettings.java:168)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.get(TerminalLineSettings.java:72)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.<init>(TerminalLineSettings.java:52)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.java:168)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:81)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:227)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:219)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:207)
    at play.console.Console$.<init>(Console.scala:14)
    at play.console.Console$.<clinit>(Console.scala)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:201)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:198)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.Error: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is working, because of language settings of MacBook Pro, change language and region to USA restart and retry again. I think that it's only in Turkey ,Thats a localized bug i suppose.its ok now working. Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1):

You must install Java JDK 1.7 to use Play! Framework

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/eLTQr-vVolY

Comment: its not what i am looking :(

Comment: Anyone have an idea ?